# R outer function Error in persp.default(x, y, z) : invalid 'z' limits

Tags: r, limits

could someone explain to me why these two pieces of codes return two diferent things? 
the first one :

```
x<-y<-seq(from=-1,to=1,by=0.1)
one<-function(x,y){
    x
}
z<-outer(x,y,FUN=one)
persp(x,y,z)
```

returns the surface it should.

while :

```
x<-y<-seq(from=-1,to=1,by=0.1)
one<-function(x,y){
    array(1, dim=length(x))
 }
 z<-outer(x,y,FUN=one)
 persp(x,y,z)
```

returns : "Error in persp.default(x, y, z = outer(x, y, one)) : invalid 'z' limits"

Comment: Not sure why that's not working, but simply changing `array(1,dim=length(x))` to `rep(1,length(x))` fixes the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the second case, plotting the plane `z=1`, you just need to specify the desired `zlim` yourself, e.g.

```
persp(x,y,z,zlim=c(0,2))
```

The `persp` function expects to plot in a 3-dimensional space. The default is to try to plot over the ranges of `x`, `y` and `z`, but in this case `z`'s range is degenerate.

Comment: thank you for your help I didn't though of degenerate other than infinity