# Increase the max.contour.segments in R

Tags: r, plot, biwavelet

I am using the plot function for biwavelet package and i keep getting this message

contour(): circular/long seglist -- set options("max.contour.segments") > 25000?

I tried the following code in R  but it do not work

```
options(max.contour.segments > "25000")
```

How can I increase the max.contour.segments in R.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
options("max.contour.segments"= 300000)
```

or any positive integer you want to.
You can check the current value by:

```
options("max.contour.segments")
```

Comment: thank you! when i tried it that it worked. but now i have another error Error in image.default(x$t, yvals, t(zvals), zlim = zlim, xlim = xlim,  : 
  invalid z limits

Comment: I'm not sure what is your exact case. But you might find these helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32054123/r-outer-function-error-in-persp-defaultx-y-z-invalid-z-limits; https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2005-May/071152.html; https://support.bioconductor.org/p/6090/